# SignalR message lost when client is navigating

Tags: signalr

I have implemented SignalR successfully.

I am using it to show init conversations between users on the site, so when one wants to chat with someone else, a simple message is sent using SignalR.

This works well, except one situation. If the request is sent the same time as the one supposed to receive it is doing a new page request, like navigating the site, the message is lost.

I can see that the messages expire after 30 seconds in the InProcMessageBus, but I do not think that is the problem, since I am testing on my machine and the page load takes max 1-2 seconds.

So, is this actually by design? Or am I doing it wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused, are you saying if you hit refresh as soon as a message is sent that it isn't received?

Comment: I think actually the message is sent to the client, it is just that the client misses it, like the event to the hub is never fired, since the browser is already in a mode of reloading the page, and when the new page reloads, the client is not getting the message, offcourse. I think you made it clear, that this is by design. So I have to keep track of the messages on the server also. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This is sort of by design. When a user creates a new connection they get a new clientid by default. This is likely the cause of the issue unless you have defined your own `IConnectionIdFactory`. If you want to make sure a client always gets the same id you would create your own implementation of this and set it like this:

```
DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IConnectionIdFactory), () => new CustomIdFactory());
```

Extensibility in SignalR - https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Extensibility

Example factory replacement for clientID: http://www.kevgriffin.com/maintaining-signalr-connectionids-across-page-instances/

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Sorry I did not mention this in the question, but I already did that. I have used the id of the user that is logged in, and looking at the request through fiddler, I can see the connectionId is the same for every request from the same user. 

So actually, my problem still persists, even that I use my own unique connectionId.